# Add HTML elements inside <tspan> element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, highcharts

JS Function:

```
response.xAxis.labels.formatter = function () {
     return ("<div title='" + this.value + "'>" + (this.value.length > 25 ? this.value.substring(0, 22) + " .." : this.value) + "</div>");
}
```

Rendered HTML On Page:

```
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="font: 11px/normal Segoe UI; width: 197px; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; fill: #555555;" text-anchor="end" x="133" y="439.8684">
    <tspan x="133">Didn’t want to sign up ..</tspan>
</text>
```

The problem is that the library is ignoring the div element of the return(). So i am not able to add the title on the text.

tested with `<span>` and `<tspan>` element also instead of `<div>`. No luck.

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I am guessing that the library does not support HTML tags because of possible XSS attacks with HTML injection. You will have to look up the documentation of highcharts.

Comment: `<text>` and `<tspan>` elements cannot have html children, not even via foreignObject.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and why do you think you can't do it with a `<tspan>` tag?

Comment: To enable HTML you could set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.useHTML) to true for axis labels.